# Как воспроизвести звук только один раз / unity C#

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть код на плеера. Пытаюсь ему сделать воспроизведение звука шагов (несколько).

Сделал через `if (controller.isGrounded)`, но воспроизводятся все выбранные в инспекторе звуки, поэтому задаюсь вопросом: "Как воспроизвести звук только один раз". Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip[] impact;
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    public float speed = 1;
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform GroundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public float gravity = 9.8f;
    public bool Sprint;


    public float jumpHeight = 3f;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public Animator anim;
    Vector3 velocity;

    bool isGrounded;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("X", ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
            anim.SetFloat("Y", ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(impact[Random.Range(0, impact.Length)]);
        }
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(GroundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }
        float x = ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if(ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)&& isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * gravity);
            anim.SetTrigger("Jump");
        }
        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        velocity.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        if (ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            audioSource.Stop();
        }
        if (ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W) && ControlFreak2.CF2Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            speed = 7f;
            anim.SetFloat("Y", 2);
            Sprint = true;
        }
        else
        {
            speed = 5f;
            Sprint = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Совет на будущее: формулировка вопроса -- 50% решения проблемы: плохо сформулированный вопрос никто не поймет и отвечать не станет. Не стесняйтесь использовать запятые, точки, заглавные буквы, а также символы *, **, и ` для курсива, жирного шрифта и куска кода

Comment: А проблема ваша, уверен, в том, что вы запускаете звук **каждый** кадр (в `Update()`). При этом звуки, запущенные в предыдущие кадры, продолжают проигрываться. Об этом написано в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html): `AudioSource.PlayOneShot does not cancel clips that are already being played by AudioSource.PlayOneShot and AudioSource.Play`. Т.е. каждый новый кадр включается новый *(у вас, рандомный)* звук, перекрывая старые, уже имеющиеся. Вам нужно пересмотреть, как и когда включать звук ходьбы.